# Configure CLION to start new CMakeList.txt with specific Standard

Tags: c++, cmake, clion

Is there a configuration in CLION to set STANDARD version?

As a new person to CLION and c++ it took me some research to understand why my tutorial Hello World wouldn't compile.  It appeared online via the other IDE which weren't CLION as location to set STANDARD etc.

It wasn't until digging here did I see someone list out set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD XX).   I then being new had to look for that line so I could figure out where it was being set to an older standard.

I couldn't find a way but, then again new to CLION on how to set this and I'm figuring there will be other like libraries, when creating a project or setting up a toolchain.

I started with MingGW 64.6.0 was what downloaded and CMAKE version 3.17.5

Comment: https://cliutils.gitlab.io/modern-cmake/

Comment: That tutorial has a section on setting the C++ standard

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly you can adjust settings in *Preferences | Editor | File and Code Templates* by adding any standard to CMakeLists.txt File template. So when creating new CMakeLists.txt it will be added automatically.